# Customize font when using style sheet

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the `'ggplot'` style sheet. Now, the style is great, except that I would like to specifically change the font style. **Is that possible?**

If found the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) about customizing styles. However, I just want to change the font while keeping the rest of the style.

**Also, does anyone know where to see the setting-details of each `style` (like font, figsize, etc.)?**

```
plt.imshow(ori, vmin = 0, vmax = 300)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. And you can do it either locally by passing the font to individual labels

```
font = {'fontname':'your font'}
plt.xlabel('xlabel', **hfont)
plt.ylabel('xlabel', **hfont)
```

or globally

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'your font'
```

Answer (score 4):

### Combining styles

I think that the most elegant is to [combine styles](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html).

For example, you could define your own font settings in `mystyle.mplstyle` (see below where to save it, and what it could look like). To get the `ggplot` style with your own font settings you would then only have to specify:

```
plt.style.use(['ggplot', 'mystyle'])
```

This solution is elegant, because it allows consistent application in all your plots and allows you to mix-and-match.

### Where to save your custom style?

Taken from one of my own styles `mystyle.mplstyle` could have the following entries (you should customise to your need obviously):

```
font.family  : serif
font.serif   : CMU Serif
font.weight  : bold
font.size    : 18
text.usetex  : true
```

Which you should save it matplotlib's configuration directory. For me this is `~/.matplotlib/stylelib/`, but use

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_configdir()
```

to find out what to use on your operating system. See [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). You could also write a Python function to install in the right location.

### Where to find existing styles?

Then the final part of your question. First, it is usefull to know that you can obtain a list with available styles using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.available
```

See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html) for a graphical representation.

How to inspect for example `ggplot.mplstyle`? I think that the best reference in [matplotlib's source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib). You can also find the `*.mplstyle` files on your system. Where, however, depends on your operating system and installation. For me

```
find / -iname 'ggplot.mplstyle' 2>/dev/null
```

gives

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/ggplot.mplstyle
```

Or more generally you could search for all styles:

```
find / -iname '*.mplstyle' 2>/dev/null
```

> For Windows I am not really an expert, but maybe the file-paths that were listed above give you a clue where to look.

### Python script to install style in the right location

To install your custom styles in the right location, you could build a script that looks something like:

```
def copy_style():

    import os
    import matplotlib

    # style definition(s)

    styles = {}

    styles['mystyle.mplstyle'] = '''
font.family          : serif
'''

    # write style definitions

    # directory name where the styles are stored
    dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(), 'stylelib'))

    # make directory if it does not yet exist
    if not os.path.isdir(dirname): os.makedirs(dirname)

    # write all styles
    for fname, style in styles.items():
        open(os.path.join(dirname, fname),'w').write(style)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's really useful and systematic!

Answer (score 1):

Try rcParams

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
```

Read more [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#figure-size-font-size-and-screen-dpi)