# How do I create and store a matplotlib style file on macOS?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to create multiple data plot templates for different publishing purposes. As a newby in Python I struggle in creating a matplotlib style file as described in the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html)! in section "Defining you own style". What is required to store a .mplstyle file?

Following the description in the documentation, I found that my folder structure (on MacOS, recent Anaconda install) does not correspond to the "required" one (the documentation says it should be `~/.config/matplotlib`). I checked that with

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_configdir()
```

and got

```
'/Users/USER1/.matplotlib'
```

Is it a problem that it is different from the one given in the docs? If yes, how do I change it to the required path?

Second, how do I create a .mplstyle file in the corresponding folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize font when using style sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706018/customize-font-when-using-style-sheet)

Comment: Hi, thank for the hint, but the referenced link does not answer my specific question either.

Comment: Maybe then I don't understand your question. I thought that you were wondering which folder to use to store your `.mplstyle' -file. From the referenced answer: `dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(), 'stylelib'))`. Can you maybe tell me were you are still stuck with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it by changing the `MPLCONFIGDIR` ENV variable.

**TL;DR:**

```
export MPLCONFIGDIR="the path you want"
```

For your second question, I am not sure if there's any function in matplotlib to create a `.mplstyle` file. But you can create the file manually under the `MPLCONFIGDIR/stylelib/` directory.

Here are the step and guide to config the path:
https://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#locating-matplotlib-config-dir

How to set the environment variable on OSX:
https://matplotlib.org/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#setting-linux-osx-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helped. I created a folder stylelib now using the terminal:
`cd /Users/USER1/.matplotlib`
`mkdir stylelib`
and I have three things in the .matplotlib folder: 
`fontlist-v300.json stylelib tex.cache` . Then, I opened Textedit and copy-pasted the style commands from the matplotlib documentation and saved it as .mplstyle style file in the stylelib folder. However, when I want to apply the style Python tells me file not found? What do I do wrong? I followed just the description from the documentation.

Comment: I also found that my `MPLCONFIGDIR` is empty, i.e. `echo $MPLCONFIGDIR` throws a blank line. Does it work anyways?

Comment: Because the MPLCONFIGDIR hasn’t been set yet. Set it with “export “ command.

Comment: Ok, I did it. `echo $MPLCONFIGDIR` throws the path `/Users/USER1/.matplotlib` now. However, after restarting the Mac it's gone. Doesn't seem right. Anyways, I set it again but Python is still telling me, that it could not find the mplstyle file. I really don't get what's wrong here. Anything I can test?

Comment: Yes, you can import ‘os’ and add an ‘assert’ statement to check whether the path is set properly or not.

Comment: The statement `os.path.isfile("/Users/USER1/.matplotlib/stylelib/presentation.mplstyle")` throws `True`. Still, the style could not be applied. But I found the problem, I needed the to restart the kernel. Now it works. Many thanks.